# Is there a roadmap for official support PHP 7 for Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7

Is there a roadmap (or will there be in the near future) for official support for `PHP 7` for `Magento 1.x`?

I know there is a [community extension](https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7) for making it compatible. And I know about the several PHP 7 topics here. But I am specifically wondering about **official** support, it would make the process a bit more convinient.

**EDIT**: I am looking for an official source or statement or maybe a post from the core team or something. In other words a source which is less opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most official statement I got is from user KAndy (M2 core developer) in "[Is Magento ready for PHP 7?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74008/is-magento-ready-for-php-7)"

> Also, support of php 7 in Magento1 require backward incompatible changes and I think will be not supported officially.

Answer (score 1):

Magento will be supporting Magento 1.x probably for the next couple of years. But most likely it'll be a security only form of support - officially it doesnt support 5.6 and PHP 5.5 is EOL now so I would not anticipate any official PHP7 support for Magento 1.x

The module you have mentioned I have used on a few projects with mostly a good success of doing so.

Some additional reading:

https://community.magento.com/t5/Version-Upgrades/What-is-the-end-of-life-date-for-Magento-1-9x-community-edition/td-p/36541

[Future Support of Magento 1.9 - Coming Magento 2.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54303/future-support-of-magento-1-9-coming-magento-2-0)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am looking for an answer less opinion based. I edited my question. Are there any sources you can add?