# Magento 1.9 CE security fixing end of life

Tags: magento-1.9, security

I just read all answers from this question: [Future Support of Magento 1.9 - Coming Magento 2.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54303/future-support-of-magento-1-9-coming-magento-2-0) 
But I can't find a clear date or an official reference about the end of life date for Magento 1.9.

Is there nothing like this?: http://php.net/supported-versions.php

I found some sentences like [this](https://community.magento.com/t5/Version-Upgrades/What-is-the-end-of-life-date-for-Magento-1-9x-community-edition/m-p/36554#M1691):

> Magento 1x will be supported for the next three years from the Magento 2.0 release date.

or [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/54305/38275):

> Will be supported for 3 years after 2.0 comes out of beta by Magento itself

or [this](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/457):

> Magento will continue to provide security updates to Magento Enterprise Edition 1.13 and 1.14 for 3 years after Magento 2.0 general availability

But it is not clear if I'm supposed to count three years from Magento 2 beta release (early 2015?) or Magento 2.0 release (late 2015) and if security updates will be only for Magento EE or Magento CE 1.9 also?

Furthermore I can't find any official reference about these claims.

Answer (score 2):

Magento stated on M2 release that they will continue to release security fixes and incremental updates for M1 until November 2018.  I would be amazed if the community at large didnt continue to support such a widely used platform, but as M2 begins to mature, its worth making the leap.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where they said this thing? Do you know if is there also an official and public note about this? Just to have an authoritative reference

Comment: @Andrea for official sources see my answer below

Comment: I disagree that M2 is ready. The class insertion creates unstable code. Then it has to be fixed every time a new extension is added. Although I was able to get some M2 extensions functional, the whole system has fundamental issues in the class insertion that are not being addressed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and like you mentioned most of what I could find were forum answers, tweets, vague blog articles, and word of mouth.

After several hours of research I found the real **sources** for that information and wrote [this article](http://bit.ly/mage1eol) to keep them handy for the near future.

> Magento 1.x Enterprise Edition will be officially supported by Magento
>   until November 17, 2018 (see the article for the sources &
>   explanation).

Notice that I mentioned Enterprise Edition: I couldn't find anything about support for Community Edition. There doesn't seem to be a formal commitment to support CE. One could say that support will trickle down from EE support, but that's just an assumption.

UPDATE (2017-06-06): On May 30th 2017 Magento [announced](https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/ongoing-magento-1-support) in their blog that Enterprise Edition support will continue for the foreseeable future. It's still not clear if they will update the legal documents to reflect that though (e.g. the Enterprise Edition Agreement). It's also not clear yet whether support will trickle down to Community Edition.

Comment: Note: there may be more sources than what I could find! If you find them please post them here or let me know as well so I can update.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gabriel. **You should keep in mind that transferring your old website to Magento 2 entails much more than simply downloading and installing the engine upgrade. In fact, the second version is a fundamentally new product that differs from the predecessor in many key points.**. My team prepared some info about it https://webmeridian.org/magento-1-end-of-life/